# is there a way to have full control over a browser in a native iOS app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, browser

I have a chrome plugin I've written that does stuff like:

- sets cookies on the user's behalf
- visits a certain sequence of urls, posting form data, and reading returned HTML and cookies
  (this has to be from a real browser, not a series of programmed http connections.)
- opens tabs to specific urls

Basically in the chrome plugin world I have complete control to do almost anything (once the user agrees and installs the plugin.)

In there any way to do this in a native iOS app?  I realize there is no plugin system for either safari or chrome on iOS.  Do I stand a chance using UIWebView?  Or is UIWebView way too limited?  Is there a complete webkit or mozilla browser code in Objective-C I can use and modify for my needs?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most definitely possible if you are building a native iOS application.

1) You can communicate with cookies with the `NSHTTPCookieStorage` APIs.

2) You can send network requests and process their data on a background queue, after which you can then set the HTML content of the `UIWebView` (on the main queue.)

3) Your "tabs" can simply be sibling view controllers which each contain a `UIWebView`.